# Change OSPF Router ID without reload

Tags: cisco, routing, router, ospf

We have setup `OSPF` on router and initial it pick ip address `70.xx.xx.33` but later we remove those IPs and reconfigure for new subnet but still `OSPF` showing older router ID sometime it's confusing seeing older IP address in Router ID, Is there a way i can tell OSPF re-initialize new ID without reload?

```
R1#sh ip ospf summary-address

            OSPF Router with ID (70.xx.xx.33) (Process ID 1)
```

## EDIT:

Its Cisco C3850 L3 switch with latest IOS running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say what model router you have, but assuming a Cisco router (from the configuration example you have) can use the `clear ip ospf process` command to clear and reload OSPF on a router.

Check the [Cisco Documentation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/iproute/command/reference/fiprrp_r/1rfospf.html):

> ## clear ip ospf
>
> To clear redistribution based on the OSPF routing process ID, use the
>   **clear ip ospf** command in privileged EXEC mode.
>
> **clear ip ospf [*pid*] {process | redistribution | counters [neighbor [*neighbor-interface*] [*neighbor-id*]]}**
>
> Syntax Description
>   - [image]
>
> ### **Usage Guidelines**
>
> Use the *pid* option to clear only one OSPF process. If the *pid*
>   option is not specified, all OSPF processes are cleared.
>
> ### **Examples**
>
> The following example clears all OSPF processes:
>
> ```
> clear ip ospf process
> ```

Comment: After googling many folks saying it won't change with `clear ip ospf` command. They said you need to manually assign ID. its production so i don't want to play. Does it create any issue in future?

Comment: What do you mean manually assign ID?

Comment: using `router-id A.B.C.D` command in OSPF.  Read comments of this post http://blog.ipspace.net/2007/10/ospf-router-id-does-not-change-when.html

Comment: You need to clear OSPF on the router where the route originated. All the other routers just repeat what it is telling them. The `router-id` command just manually assigns the router ID, and it is a best practice to do this and assign it to a Loopback address, otherwise the router-ID could change from time to time, as the router gets reloaded.

Comment: Does it cause any issue if we reload router and it change Router-ID? we have only 3 router in OSPF and it's very simple network. Should i worried about Router ID or just ignore it and let it run its own.

Comment: You should probably set the router IDs manually. This won't actually change the router ID until you restart the device.

Comment: Should i put new IP address of physical interface? also i ping you for chat because i have more question http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations

Comment: can i just do `router-id 1.1.1.1` without loopback etc.. does that will work? we have only 3 router in OS and not going to expand in future also

Comment: You could, but then, if you decide to use a loopback address to source other protocols, the OSPF router ID won't match. It's nice to have a single address for everything, and just by looking at a router ID or IP address, you know which router it is.