# OSPF Configuration: Router ID won't change to loopback address

Tags: cisco, router, ospf

I am new to this so forgive me for mistakes, but I feel like I am missing something here.

I am trying to use a loopback address as the router ID for Router0 in my network. I am typing in:

```
Router(config)#int loopback 0
Router(config-if)#ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#do show ip int brief
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol 
FastEthernet0/0        150.45.101.1    YES manual up                    up 
FastEthernet1/0        unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
Serial2/0              200.200.200.3   YES manual up                    up 
Serial3/0              unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
FastEthernet4/0        unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
FastEthernet5/0        unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
Loopback0              1.1.1.1         YES manual up                    up
Router(config)#
```

So we can see that the loopback has been configured, but when I show the router ID it is still showing the serial interface as its ID.

```
Router(config)#do show ip ospf
 Routing Process "ospf 100" with ID 200.200.200.3
Supports only single TOS(TOS0) routes
 Supports opaque LSA
 It is an area border router
 SPF schedule delay 5 secs, Hold time between two SPFs 10 secs
 Minimum LSA interval 5 secs. Minimum LSA arrival 1 secs
 Number of external LSA 0. Checksum Sum 0x000000
 Number of opaque AS LSA 0. Checksum Sum 0x000000
 Number of DCbitless external and opaque AS LSA 0
 Number of DoNotAge external and opaque AS LSA 0
 Number of areas in this router is 2. 2 normal 0 stub 0 nssa
 External flood list length 0
    Area BACKBONE(0) (Inactive)
        Number of interfaces in this area is 0
        Area has no authentication
        SPF algorithm executed 5 times
        Area ranges are
        Number of LSA 2. Checksum Sum 0x0137ce
        Number of opaque link LSA 0. Checksum Sum 0x000000
        Number of DCbitless LSA 0
        Number of indication LSA 0
        Number of DoNotAge LSA 0
        Flood list length 0
    Area 1
        Number of interfaces in this area is 1
        Area has no authentication
        SPF algorithm executed 2 times
        Area ranges are
        Number of LSA 0. Checksum Sum 0x000000
        Number of opaque link LSA 0. Checksum Sum 0x000000
        Number of DCbitless LSA 0
        Number of indication LSA 0
        Number of DoNotAge LSA 0
        Flood list length 0
```

To resolve this problem I tried this:

```
Router(config)#do clear ip ospf process
Reset ALL OSPF processes? [no]: y
Router(config)#
```

But when I run this command again I am getting the same results:

```
Router(config)#do show ip ospf
 Routing Process "ospf 100" with ID 200.200.200.3
Supports only single TOS(TOS0) routes
 Supports opaque LSA
 It is an area border router
 SPF schedule delay 5 secs, Hold time between two SPFs 10 secs
 Minimum LSA interval 5 secs. Minimum LSA arrival 1 secs
 Number of external LSA 0. Checksum Sum 0x000000
 Number of opaque AS LSA 0. Checksum Sum 0x000000
 Number of DCbitless external and opaque AS LSA 0
 Number of DoNotAge external and opaque AS LSA 0
 Number of areas in this router is 2. 2 normal 0 stub 0 nssa
 External flood list length 0
    Area BACKBONE(0) (Inactive)
        Number of interfaces in this area is 0
        Area has no authentication
        SPF algorithm executed 5 times
        Area ranges are
        Number of LSA 2. Checksum Sum 0x0137ce
        Number of opaque link LSA 0. Checksum Sum 0x000000
        Number of DCbitless LSA 0
        Number of indication LSA 0
        Number of DoNotAge LSA 0
        Flood list length 0
    Area 1
        Number of interfaces in this area is 1
        Area has no authentication
        SPF algorithm executed 2 times
        Area ranges are
        Number of LSA 0. Checksum Sum 0x000000
        Number of opaque link LSA 0. Checksum Sum 0x000000
        Number of DCbitless LSA 0
        Number of indication LSA 0
        Number of DoNotAge LSA 0
        Flood list length 0
```

And here is the running-config:

```
Router(config-if)#do show running-config

Building configuration...

Current configuration : 887 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 150.45.101.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 ip address 200.200.200.3 255.255.255.0
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet4/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet5/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 100
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 150.45.101.0 0.0.0.7 area 0
 network 200.200.200.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
end
```

As we can see the router ID did not change, what is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to give us more of the configuration. For example, the OSPF configuration could have a specific router ID configured (recommended as a best practice). The best thing is to edit your question with the full router configuration.

Comment: Unfamiliar with how to make it show up exactly as is shown on packet tracer, so you may have to edit the post again, but is this what you are looking for when you are asking for the full router configuration? Everything I have pasted here is the only thing I have done thus far on this router.

Comment: What I mean is, edit your question to include the full running configuration (`show running-config`). Simply paste it into the question, and use the Preformatted Text (`{}`) button on it.

Comment: Okay I see, added the running-config.

Comment: Likely, this is a bug in Packet Tracer. There are many small problems that you will find in it. You could try removing the OSPF (`no router ospf 100`), then add it back to see if it picks up the loopback. If not, it may be that you are not including that interface in the OSPF process. It is hard to say what Packet Tracer is doing. The best practice is to specifically set the OSPF router ID with the `router-id <router-id>` command.

Comment: Removing the OSPF then adding it back worked in Packet Tracer. I will remember to just specifically set the OSPF router ID in the future just in case.

Comment: You should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change OSPF Router ID without reload](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33653/change-ospf-router-id-without-reload)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply clearing the process may not be enough to re-start the RID selection process.  That said, as Ron points out in the comments, it is **by far** best practice to manually specify the router ID in OSPF (and, indeed, **all** dynamic protocols) to avoid this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and tried to use ***clear ip ospf process*** as well. I ended up reloading the devices that were using OSPF for the changes to take effect. You could potentially use the ***router-id [router-id in IP address notation]*** command in the OSPF router config mode and then run ***clear ip ospf process*** to see if that works (I have not tested that method). Also, ***show ip protocols*** is another way to get detail on ip routing and it might be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

do wr
reload
200.200.200.3>>>1.1.1.1

Assuming you are using GNS3